# Access IP address of a server running in lan network from inside docker

Tags: docker, networking

I have a docker container running, but I am not able to access an IP address of a server running on same network where my host machine is running.

For example run a docker container with following command

```
docker run -it --entrypoint bash debian:stable-slim
```

And enter following command for using pingutils

```
apt-get update && apt-get -u iputils-ping
```

Now if I ping the server running on my local network, I don't get response.
[image]

Similarly I am not able to access any ip address that are running on my lan network from inside docker container.

My docker is configured to use following ip addresses
[image]

Whereas docker network's inspection output is as followed

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "0a86e625c875ba2beb828664c5bc917f977056f5b1fc63612db1086ad7ae7e58",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {},
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/0a86e625c875",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "b1646887e464da02a1ce21bfb550f44094704b8db5e8ce9729cfa9f48d064c2e",
    "Gateway": "192.168.0.1",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "192.168.0.2",
    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:02",
    "Networks": {
        "bridge": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": null,
            "NetworkID": "cbfeb95807852ce2d1e56025b6115ddef322971d120f0f9ff29ba1f234a3ff1f",
            "EndpointID": "b1646887e464da02a1ce21bfb550f44094704b8db5e8ce9729cfa9f48d064c2e",
            "Gateway": "192.168.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "192.168.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 24,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:02",
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is docker is using the same ip pool to assign to containers as my lan dhcp. I need to update docker configuration to use different IP pool for bridge network.

That could be done by adding following entry in Docker Engine settings.

```
"default-address-pools": [
  {
    "base": "172.30.0.0/16",
    "size": 24
  }
],
```

This settings are available at Preference > Docker Engine
[image]